# installation error for brostrend ac3 wifi adapter

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel

I am trying to install a brostrend ac3 1200 mbps wifi adapter on my desktop and keep running into problems during the installation. I am trying to install the drivers but they aren't available on ubuntu yet. when trying to compile the kernel module, i receive this error:

```
root@chris-pc:~# cd rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux

root@chris-pc:~/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux# make

make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-119-generic/build M=/root/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux  modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-119-generic'
  CC [M]  /root/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o
/root/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:809:2: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror]
  .ndo_select_queue = rtw_select_queue,
  ^
/root/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:809:2: error: (near initialization for ‘rtw_netdev_ops.ndo_select_queue’) [-Werror]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/root/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/root/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-119-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
root@chris-pc:~/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux#
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where did you get the code? Here? https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux  Or here? https://github.com/bits3rpent/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux

Comment: https://blog.danielscrivano.com/installing-rtl8812au-on-linux-for-wireless-dual-band-usb-adapters/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try this package instead; with a working internet connection by ethernet, tethered or whatever means possible:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/bits3rpent/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.git
cd rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8812au
```